# How to rename all the files in a directory to a particular format?

Tags: bash, rename

I have a directory in which I have lot of files in this format only. Below are just examples for two of my files.

```
file_948_of_2000_push_data_12345.log
file_950_of_2000_push_data_12345.log
```

As you can see only difference is this file number `948` and `950`. Now I want to rename all these files in this particular format as shown below:

```
files_948.log
files_950.log
```

What is the best way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using shell parameter expansion

```
$ for f in *.log; do g="${f/#file_/}"; echo mv -- "$f" "files_${g%%_*}.log"; done
mv -- file_948_of_2000_push_data_12345.log files_948.log
mv -- file_950_of_2000_push_data_12345.log files_950.log
```

Using the perl-based `prename` or `rename` command

```
$ prename -n -- 's/^(.*?)_(.*?)_.*\.log$/$1s_$2.log/' *.log
file_948_of_2000_push_data_12345.log renamed as files_948.log
file_950_of_2000_push_data_12345.log renamed as files_950.log
```

Using `mmv`

```
$ mmv -n '*_*_*.log' '#1s_#2.log'
file_948_of_2000_push_data_12345.log -> files_948.log
file_950_of_2000_push_data_12345.log -> files_950.log
```

Remove the `-n` or `echo` as appropriate.

Comment: awesome.. works like a charm. Thanks You! Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command:

```
  ls -C1 file*log |  perl -ane 'chomp;$d=$_; s/^(\w+?)_(\d+?)_.*/$1s_$2.log/; print "mv -v $d $_\n";' | bash
```

The perl script generates the command for the move.  Leave off the pipe to bash to see if the command does what you want.  The perl one-line reads the list of files from stdin and the matches the first word followed by an underscore followed by a group of digits and then prints the move command.  If you need it for something other than linux, perl can simply rename the file for you.  Caveats.  The one-liner is raw and won't handle filenames with a path.

Comment: I think it mostly worked.. Only thing doesn't work is - it didn't added `s` to `file`? Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I missed that subtety.  It should work now.